# Javascript 'OnClick' and HTML <a href> Not Working When Used Together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to perform certain functions when the next button is clicked but when I use onclick with `<a href>` it doesn't work. I've tried to use JavaScript and jQuery methods but both failed.

Here is the HTML next button code:

```
<a href="#" id="nextButt" onclick="performNextAction()" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
```

Here is the jQuery Syntax:

```
$("nextButt").on('click', function() {
  alert(""You clicked Next Button in Jquery");
})
```

Here is the JavaScript Syntax

```
function performNextAction(){
  alert("You clicked Next Button in Javascript")
}
```

Comment: How did it "fail"? What isn't working? Are you getting any errors in the console? Note that in your jQuery example you have a problem with your quotes `alert(""`

Comment: well the alert has a syntax error.... Some Browser pop up blocker's also has issues with multiple alerts being fired.

Comment: @j08691nothing happens.. The button doesn't do anything.

Comment: @epascarello Noticed but it was just an error i made when i was retyping the code here but theres no error in the code in my editor.

Comment: Well impossible to help you with the information provided if there is no typo. Look at the developer console in your browser and look for error messages. We need more details to help you out....

Comment: You should use # to select the id : `$("#nextButt")`.  You also have an error of quote : `alert(""You clicked Next Button in Jquery");` should be `alert("You clicked Next Button in Jquery");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
 <a id="nextButt" onclick="performNextAction()" class="next round">&#8250;</a>

<script>
function performNextAction(){
      alert("You clicked Next Button in Javascript");
      window.location.href = "#";
}
</script>
```

Comment: It just worked for me now.  I mean coding is so delicate. It didn't work for me 30 mins ago with a small change the whole program works as expected. Thanks for your answer @jolle

Comment: @BoringProgrammer - yeah, coding is delicate, you'd be surprised how much something like `;` could break a program that only needed `:` ;)

Answer (score -1):

I found the bug. I solved it with JQuery.

Here is the working code:

```
$("#nextButt").on('click', function() {
alert("You clicked Next Button in Jquery");
```

})

What was the bug?

You will notice that in the first line of JQuery code i write, i omitted the '#' sign. 
Refer here: `$("nextButt").on('click', function()`

but now with the '#' sign included it works well.

I beat myself up only to go walk around and come back to see the bug right in my face.. Phheew!LOL!